# Evaluate values within expression function

Tags: r, expression, eval

Using the R language, if I want to plug in some real (evaluated) values in the expression and keep other parameters unresolved, what should I do? For example:

```
> b = 1
> a = 2
> expr = expression(b+a)
> expr
expression(b+a)
> eval(expr)
[1] 3
```

But what if I want the expr equal to

```
expression(1+a)
```

How can I preprocess the variable *b*?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you do not need to evaluate, since what you need is an expression. you need to `substitute`:

```
a <- 2
b <- 1
substitute(expression(b + a),list(b=1))
expression(1 + a)
```